# Phalcon Unittest Not Working

Tags: php, phalcon

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in /vagrant/cmol-rule-engine-v2.0/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:1066
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/cmol-rule-engine-v2.0/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(163): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 /usr/bin/phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
thrown in /vagrant/cmol-rule-engine-v2.0/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 1066
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the problem ?

Comment: How to call another function inside unit test function. It shows error like Call to undefined method Test\UnitTest::getInterestRateValues().  Kindly explain what to do

Comment: Iam trying to call functions in different classes also i had given the namespaces also but  it shows call to undefined method.   $this->assertEquals(
            35,
            $this->getInterestRateValues($context, $gridContext),
            "This is OK"
        );

Comment: It seems your function `assertEquals` is not accessible, However you have given namespaces on top, So, the reason for not accessible might be solved if it is defined in base controller or something like that [This might help you](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/536/how-to-unit-testing-controller-action-)